# Annotating variables in replacement rules

Tags: replacement

How do you decorate or annotate a variable in a replacement rule?

For example

```
{(e[(-X + Y)^2 || f])} //. {e[(-a_ + b_)^2 || f] -> (-a + b)^2}
```

Would ideally return:

> (-lagXdt + lagYdt)^2

**Update:**
The following does not return `lagXdt` and `lagYdt` but rather `lagadt` and `lagbdt`:

```
{(e[(-X + Y)^2 || f])} //. {e[(-a_ + b_)^2 || 
     f] -> (-Symbol["lag" <> ToString@a <> "dt"] + 
      Symbol["lag" <> ToString@b <> "dt"])^2}
```

Comment: Your code sample is ... quite wrong. You should balance your parentheses and check what the `//` was supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it eventually, the key was to use `:>` instead of `->`:

```
{(e[(-X + Y)^2 || f])} //. {e[(-a_ + b_)^2 || f] :> (-Symbol["lag" <> ToString@a <> "dt"] + Symbol["lag" <> ToString@b <> "dt"])^2}
```

> {(-lagXdt + lagYdt)^2